# Cannot import form_for_model

Tags: python, django, django-forms

## Here is forms.py

Can anyone tell me why am I unable to import **form_for_model**
and am I assuming that form_for_model is inbuilt?

```
from django import forms
from models import Publisher
from django.forms import form_for_model
PublisherForm = form_for_model(Publisher)
TOPIC_CHOICES = (
      ('general', 'General enquiry'),
      ('bug', 'Bug report'),
      ('suggestion', 'Suggestion'),
      )
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
           topic = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TOPIC_CHOICES)
           message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
           sender = forms.EmailField(required=False)
           def clean_message(self):
                     message = self.clean_data.get('message', '')
                     num_words = len(message.split())
                     if num_words < 4:
                         raise forms.ValidationError("Not enough words!")
                     return message
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea to use `form_for_model`? It was removed *nine* versions ago.

Comment: i was following a olderbook pdf . Now i am following the Django online Documentation. i got the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

`form_for_model` is depreciated use `ModelForm` instead ,

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
       topic = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TOPIC_CHOICES)
       ....
```

You can find docs at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm

Comment: Sorry i was following older book. so i got that problem. Now i got the solution

Comment: glad you solved this!

Answer (score 1):

`form_for_model` was removed, you should use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/) instead
[check this already removed](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges#Removedseveralmoredeprecatedfeaturesfor1.0)

> ```
> from django.forms import ModelForm
> from myapp.models import Publisher
> ....
> ....
> # Create the form class.
> class ContactForm(forms.Form):
>            topic = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TOPIC_CHOICES)
>            message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
>            sender = forms.EmailField(required=False)
> ....
> ....
> ```

Comment: thanks bro this is the exact solution

Comment: no problem! happy to help